# Unable to write on mounted USB drive using ftp server on android

Tags: android, apache, ftp

I have implemented a small ftp server for android using apache.ftpserver library. Now when i connect to the ftp server from a client, I am able to read and write the sd-cards contents. When I try to read mounted USB drive, I am able to do that too. But the problem comes when I try to write something on the USB. It is not allowing me to write anything on the USB.

Looking at the directory persmissions from ftp client i can see that the USB drive doesn't have write persmissions (W) but only has execute permissions (X).

I am relatively new to the android development and this problem might seem lame to experts but i still want to ask that is there something I need to do extra to make the USB write enabled.

My implementation for the server is very simple and is almost identical to the one in this post.

http://ahmedzubayr.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/ftp-server-using-apache-ftpserver-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason for the problem is that the USB drives are mounted with media_rw group and this group only has permissions to write anything to the disk.

Now from an applications perspective it needs two things.

1. WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE uses permissions in the application manifest.
2. Signing the application with the same key that was used to sign the android OS.

The first step is to make sure that the app should be able to write to the folders which are in media_rw group. The second step is needed because the permission to write to media_rw group folder only lies with either system apps or the apps that are signed with the same key as the android OS.

With these two added changes writing to USB drives works like a charm.